# Rules Not working in Formating Condition in InfoPath 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath-rules

When I add two or more conditions under one rule and try it in a preview, the rule does not work based on the conditions. However, when I have only one condition in the rule, it works.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your rules in combination work as you expect. It is common to misunderstand how each rule will AND or OR to the second. I suggest you place a “calculated value” of each rule on your view so you can see how the rule is evaluated. Then add another “calculated value” which combines the rule, and so on. Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to get a certain information displayed only when either of a couple of boxes are checked. This is the formula I have: Field1 is not equal to "True" AND Field2 is not equal to "True". Whenever I combine both conditions, it does not work. However, if I remove either of the condition, it will work. Now, I am forced to have duplicates of information that needs to be displayed when the above fields are checked. When both fields/boxes are checked, I currently see the same information twice because I have the same rules on two different fields.